# Facebook API Login - Error Only On Mobile Device

Tags: facebook-login

I've implemented Facebook login as a mobile web. But there is something wrong.
When I click the login button, it jumps out the authentication page.
After pressing confirm, it should jump back to my original page and with status logged in.
However, on both iPhone and hTc, it just won't come back to the page.
But when I manually refresh again the original page, I'm logged in.
The login function works well when I use my PC to login, but got error on iPhone and hTc.
In other word, this issue **only appears on my mobile device.**

Comment: if the error is due to implementation, then there is not enough information